# It will be possible to create, edit, delete contacts with Google People Api?

Tags: google-contacts-api, google-people-api

Now for create, edit, delete contacts you need to use the Google Contacts Api.

Google suggests:

> For read-only access to users' contacts, use the People API, which
>   provides both contact and profile information, and does not use the
>   older GData protocol.

They say also that eventually People Api will replace Contacts Api.

Do you think that in future the Google People Api allow to create, edit, delete contacts?

**Update**

As Amos Yuen said, Google updated the People Api thus you can use it also for create, edit, delete contancts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! Google plans on adding support for mutating contacts, as well as reading and mutating contact groups. Those features are under development, stay tuned for their release.

Comment: Mutation features are now released: https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2017/07/google-people-api-now-supports-updates.html